# Extract number from alpha-numeric column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input df

```
Code               Value
USH0001108421891  -9999    
USH0001108421892  -9999 X3 
USH0001108421893  -77EX3 
USH0001108421894   483EQ3 
USH0001108421895   325EX3 
USH0001108421896   297ES3
```

As can be seen from the example, the column `Value` has both strings and integers. But I want the only the first set of integers before the alphabets.

Expected df

```
Code               Value
USH0001108421891  -9999    
USH0001108421892  -9999 
USH0001108421893  -77
USH0001108421894   483
USH0001108421895   325
USH0001108421896   297
```

I tried this, but it returned an error .

```
df1['Value'] = df1['Value'].astype(int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-77EX3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`regex pattern`](https://regex101.com/r/3AlM2x/1) containing capturing group:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.extract(r'^(-?\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
```

---

```
              Code   Value
0  USH0001108421891  -9999
1  USH0001108421892  -9999
2  USH0001108421893    -77
3  USH0001108421894    483
4  USH0001108421895    325
5  USH0001108421896    297
```

Comment: Very slightly modified your code and it worked for me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  `df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.extract(r'^(-?\d+)', expand=False).astype(float)`

Comment: @RoshanShah22 Happy coding!